# How to use mfc in de dll using def file

Tags: c++, plugins, dll, mfc

I'm writing a plugin for a musicplayer named MusicBee.
I got one problem writing it. I must use mfc for a lot of thinks. Such as hbitmap, special timers and other stuff. But every time I change "Use of MFC" in VS2012 from "Use standard Windows library" to "use mfc ..." my code doenst compile. The problem is a def file that I must use for the plugin of MusicBee.

The def file looks like:

```
LIBRARY "mb_LogitechPlugin" 
EXPORTS   
    Initialise @1 
    Configure @2
    Close @3
    Uninstall @4
    ReceiveNotification @5
    RetrieveLyrics @6
    RetrieveArtwork @7
    SaveSettings @8
    Refresh @9
    IsReady @10
    GetIcon @11
    FolderExists @12
    GetFolders @13
    GetFiles @14
    FileExists @15
    GetFile @16
    GetFileArtwork @17
    GetPlaylists @18
    GetPlaylistFiles @19
    GetStream @20
    GetError @21
```

All other code can be found at:
https://bitbucket.org/jimmyD/musicbee-logitech-applet/src

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use MFC at all.

MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes) are nothing more than a (bad) wrapper around the Win32 API.  you do not need to use it all.  If there are special things that MFC is doing for you that you cannot figure out, I suggest that you look at the included MFC source.  It really is not worth it, just to get at HBITMAP or some other things.